# Restore game state in cocos2d-android

Tags: android, android-activity, cocos2d-android

My game engine uses `cocos2d-android` framework.

If the activity goes to the background and resumes (`onStop` and `onRestart` functions are overriden) how can I load the original game state to the resumed `CCScene` (with player positions, sounds, colors, etc...)

I tried the standard way - save variables and load in `onRestart`.

My gameline is: `welcomescreen - menu1layer - menu2layer - gamelayer CCScene`

It is possible?

What is the best solution for pausing & resuming the game after power key pressed for example?